# mysql date update row when pass 3 days

Tags: php, mysql, sql

[image]

I have a sql for date in mysql. I want to update the row with the date that pass 3days on the current date.

I want to update this date 2018-09-08. But the 2018-09-11 date is the one that changing the status.

[image]

```
$query = $this->db->query("UPDATE reservation SET status='CANCELED' WHERE date_reserve > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY");
```

Whats wrong with my code? Thanks

Comment: Execute `SELECT * FROM reservation WHERE date_reserve > CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY`. Do you get the expected result?

Comment: `<` or maybe `<=` you will have to test the `<=` does what you want or not

Answer (score 1):

I think the directxion of comparison is in the wrong direction:

```
UPDATE reservation
    SET status = 'CANCELED'
    WHERE date_reserve <= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY;
```

Or, perhaps:

```
   WHERE date_reserve >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 4 DAY AND
         date_reserve < CURDATE() - INTERVAL 3 DAY
```